# Run Background Task every day in UWP App

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I've created an app with a background task. Now I'm searching for an option to run this task every day or after system start.

Is there such an option? Can't find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might want to look at Quartz.net.

Answer (score 2):

What about creating a `BackgroundTask` with a `TimeTrigger` ?

**1. Creation of TimeTrigger**

```
bool oneShot = false;
TimeTrigger hourlyTrigger = new TimeTrigger(60*24, oneShot );
```

**2. Creation of the BackgroundTask**

```
string entryPoint = “Tasks.ExampleBackgroundTaskClass”;
string taskName   = “Example daily background task”;

BackgroundTaskRegistration task = RegisterBackgroundTask(entryPoint, taskName, hourlyTrigger, null);
```

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186458.aspx

Comment: But when I register the background task at 5pm for example, it will run every day at 5pm instead of running directly after system start on the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this helper

```
**public class BackgroundActionTask
{
    private const string Task_NAME = "BackgroundTasker";
    public async static void RunBacgroundTask(bool run)
    {
        if (run)
        {
            StorageHelper.SaveLocalSetting(BuiltSettings.BackroundTaskKey, Task_NAME);
        }
        else
        {
            if (StorageHelper.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey(BuiltSettings.BackroundTaskKey))
            {
                StorageHelper.LocalSettings.Values.Remove(BuiltSettings.BackroundTaskKey);
            }
        }
        if (StorageHelper.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey(BuiltSettings.BackroundTaskKey))
        {
            foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                task.Value.Unregister(true);
            }
            var access = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

            switch (access)
            {
                case BackgroundAccessStatus.Unspecified:
                    break;
                case BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedMayUseActiveRealTimeConnectivity:
                    break;
                case BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedWithAlwaysOnRealTimeConnectivity:
                    break;
                case BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            try
            {
                var task = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
                {
                    Name = Task_NAME,
                    TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BackgroundTasker.BackgroundTaskUpdater).ToString()
                };

                var trigger = new TimeTrigger(12 * 60, false);
                task.SetTrigger(trigger);
                task.Register();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DialogHelper.DisplayMessageDebug(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                task.Value.Unregister(true);
            }
        }
    }**
```

Add to Component Library

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        // Get a deferral, to prevent the task from closing prematurely
        // while asynchronous code is still running.
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        var successTask = await ExecuteBackgrounTaskAsync();
        // when all task is completed...
        if(successTask)
             deferral.Complete();
    }
```